# Call a function in surfaceview class from a fragment in android

Tags: android-fragments, methods, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview class in which there is a  method updateValue(). This surface view is inside a fragment(framelayout). I am trying to call the method updateValue() from the fragment class. But it is not working.

```
public class ImageSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {
......
        public void updateValue(int message){
        .......

        }
}
```

xml file in which this surfaceview is declared.
fragment_main.xml --->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.paint.drawx.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<com.paint.drawx.ImageSurface
    android:id ="@+id/imagesurface1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</FrameLayout> 

 <fragment android:name="com.paint.drawx.DrawTools"
      android:id="@+id/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#FF889911"
                />
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment class ----

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageSurface imageSurface;
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
        //imageSurface = (ImageSurface)findViewById(R.id.imagesurface1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);

        imageSurface = (ImageSurface)activity.findViewById(R.id.imagesurface1);
    }

    public void setMessage(int mess){
        try{
        imageSurface.updateValue(mess);////////this is not working. gives error nullpoint exception
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("error","is"+e.toString());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

in the above class there is a method setMessage from which i call the method updateValue of the ImageSurface class  but it gives null point exception. what am i doing wrong .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line from onAttach()  method

```
imageSurface = (ImageSurface)activity.findViewById(R.id.imagesurface1);
```

and inserted this line in onCreateView()

```
imageSurface = (ImageSurface) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesurface1);
```

and every thing is fine